# iPhone error: Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGABRT"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have defined a property in application delegate.h and synthesized it in delegate.m file to make it global and to assign and to get its value from entire application:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *accountsList;
```

In mainviewcontroller I am assigning NSArray *accounts value to this global value like this:

```
((VektorAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).accountsList = accounts;
```

And in pickerviewcontroller I am assigning its value to another array like:

```
 accountsArray = ((VektorAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).accountsList;
```

And then assign it to a picker view as:

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [accounts count]; //Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGABRT"
}
```

Now here at this point I point I get an error and my application is crashing, sometimes it works and sometimes it gives error. I am not getting what would be the issue.

Comment: In what class are you calling the pickerview? Because you are using `[accounts count]` where before you named it `accountsArray`. So why aren't you using `return [accountsArray count];` ?

Comment: accountsArray is being is used in main view to check if there is one account or more. and accounts is being used in picker view account where all those accounts would be shown in picker view so that user would choose his account

Comment: Is it possible that you have it being released at some point?  Returning nil on a numberofRows method wouldn't crash it, but passing NULL to the count method would.

Comment: I am not releasing it manually as I am using ARC.

Comment: I still don't understand where you are getting `return [accounts count];` from. Instead of writing "in one view controller" and "in another view controller" give them some names so it's easier to define what's happening for us.. :P

Comment: You know what I think?  I think you aren't alloc and init'ing this array.  Setting a NULL object equal to a non-nil object does not count as initialization :p

Comment: oh you are genius CodaFi ... thanks for the guideline :)

Comment: can u post the error on the console? i bet it is stated there

Comment: No, it was not giving any error! Application was just crashing without any error and what I was getting was highlighted in green in my main.m  and sometimes  return [accounts count]; //Thread 1: Program received signal: "SIGABRT"
} as I mentioned above. Now issue has been resolved

Comment: good for you congrats :)

Comment: Thanx. I am experiencing another problem please help me with this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711145/nsuserdefaults-values-are-not-getting-saved-iphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got an idea... Make a method to check if both array's are equal.  So something like

```
if ([(Appdelegate*).....delegate.array isEqualToArray:Accountslist]) {NSLog:(@"equal")}
```

If it NSLog's correctly, you're screwed... But if it doesn't, then it just means you aren't correctly initializing your array.

Answer (score 1):

Here In Your Code You received **SIGABRT**.

So firstly you will try to know the Reason Behind That **SIGABRT**,You can Easily Fix Out That **SIGABRT**.

I'd like to tell ,**SIGABRT** basically occurs For many Reason.

1)when we are trying to access the deAllocated(Released) Instance/Object

2)or sending the Release message to The already deAllocated(Released) Instance/Object.

3)And Many More...

So for knowing the Exact reason behind that SIGABRT Message.

You should set the **NSZombieEnabled** Flag To **YES** in Environment Variable.

you can set This **NSZombieEnabled** As Below

****Product->New Scheme->Environment Variable**

**Under Environment Variable Click on "+" button****

Then Type **NSZombieEnabled** and Set **YES** Corresponding to its Flag Value.

I Hope It'll Help You to fix out that SIGABRT Prob.