# NSUserDefaults values are not getting saved iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Using the below code to save the sessionID.

```
 NSUserDefaults *sessions = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[sessions setObject:sID forKey:@"sessionsID"];

[sessions synchronize];

NSLog(@"Session Value Saved");
```

The code to retrieve the value is:

```
NSUserDefaults *sessions = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString *myString = [sessions stringForKey:@"sessionsID"];

NSLog(@"nsuser: %@", myString);
```

But on console it is showing like:

```
2012-01-03 15:37:37.292 LoginTest[574:12503] sID: c339af83caa5355d124f70e3f22c193d
2012-01-03 15:37:37.296 LoginTest[574:12503] Session Value Saved
2012-01-03 15:37:37.297 LoginTest[574:12503] Accounts: ("uid=demo@url.com", "o=Demo","o=Und")
2012-01-03 15:37:37.302 LoginTest[574:12503] sID: (null)
2012-01-03 15:37:37.304 LoginTest[574:12503] Session Value Saved
2012-01-03 15:37:37.304 LoginTest[574:12503] Accounts: (null)
2012-01-03 15:37:37.305 LoginTest[574:12503] No Session created
```

why is it being called two times and once it saves the values and shows them up and second time giving null.

I am using ARC.

I am messed-up with this... please guide me how can I resolve this issue

Comment: the code you use to retrieve the value will be helpful to us too

Comment: what type of object is `sID` ?

Comment: this works Perfectly for me... :| taking sID is NSString

Comment: wheres the output of NSLog(@"nsuser: %@", myString);
??? I have tried your code works fine for me

Comment: check out the place from where you are calling the function to store the sID in nsuserdefault

Comment: the doc says about `stringValue` : or nil if the default does not exist or does not contain a string. I bet that `sID` does not contain a string

Comment: but as per console output, at first it shows that sID is having value which is sID: c339af83caa5355d124f70e3f22c193d and second time it shows null... :(

Comment: Then you need to find out why your save method is being called a second time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We dont know why it's getting called twice; it's your app :)

Put a breakpoint on `[sessions setObject:sID forKey:@"sessionsID"];`

The first time this gets hit `sID` will be valid.

Then something is happening that is invalidating `sID` :(

The second time it gets hit it looks like `sID` is `null` - you should be able to use the console / stack to work out why it's being called twice.